# nested loops with accumulation in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to create a scheme vector with dimensions n^{2} by n^{2} (so if n=4 this is a 16 by 16 matrix, if n=5 it is a 25 by 25 matrix) where each element is an integer given by the following (the value of the element has to be always between 1 and n*n)

```
x=0
for i=0 to n-1 
  for j=0 to n-1
    for k=0 to n*n-1
       vector[n(i - 1) + j + k]= x (mod n*n)+ 1 
       x = x+1
    x= x + n 
  x=x+1
```

I started down the following path but I am not sure how to do the x accumulation in scheme

```
(define (generate-vector n)
   (define w (* n n))
   (for*/vector  ([row (in-range n)]
              [col (in-range n)]
              [k (in-range w)])
              ; TO DO))
```

Comment: What is the result of `(generate-vector 3)` ?
The statement `vector[n(i - 1) + j][k] = ...` suggest that vector is a an array and not a vector. Do you want to generate one large vector with length `n*n` or a vector of vectors of vectors?

Comment: Also in your pseudo-code: are the vector-indices 0 or 1 based?

Comment: The vector-indices are 0 based. I fixed the pseudo code

Comment: The result of (generate-vector 3) should be #(1 2 3 ...) i.e. each element of the vector is an integer. Yes the pseudo code uses an array but I would like to flatten it into a vector. One large vector with n^{4} elements (length). So for n=4 thats a vector with 256 elements.

Comment: You pseudo-code suggests a vector of vectors (since you are using two indices:  `vector[n(i - 1) + j][k] = ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want an `n x n` vector, where each element is a different integer starting from `1`. Try this:

```
(define (generate-vector n)
  (for/vector ([i (in-range n)])
    (build-vector n (lambda (j) (+ (* n i) j 1)))))
```

For example:

```
(generate-vector 3)
=> '#(#(1 2 3) #(4 5 6) #(7 8 9))
```

Comment: Should be '#(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 ...). All integers. But your code is very close.

Comment: @JennyToy I still don't get what you want as output. Is it a vector of vectors (a "matrix") or a one-dimension vector? and why is it repeating after the 9th value? please define _clearly_, for a value of `n` you specify, the _exact_ output you need.

Comment: @JennyToy In other words: write a sample input with expected output as part of the question, always do this for your questions, it's easier than trying to explain people what you want to do with non-working pseudocode.

Comment: Thats a good point. Lets say n=2. Then I would like the vector of 16 elements '#(1 2 3 4 2 3 4 1 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3). Basically the first n^{2} elements are the digits from 1 to n^{2} in that order and then from 2 to n^{2} then 1 in that order, and so on (cycling)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an almost literal translation of your pseudo-code:

```
(define (generate-vector n)
  (define n^2 (* n n))
  (define v (make-vector n^2))
  (define x 0)
  (for ([i n])
    (for ([j n])
      (for ([k n^2])
        (vector-set! v (+ (* n i) j) (+ (modulo x n^2) 1))
        (set! x (+ x 1)))
      (set! x (+ x n)))
    (set! x (+ x 1)))
  v)

(generate-vector 3)
```

Note 1: `(- i 1)` was changed to `i`  (otherwise you get negative indices when `i=0`.

Note 2: I omitted the `+k` since that leads to indices too large.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments rather than the original question, I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
(define generate-vector
  (lambda (n)
    (let ((template (iota (* n n) 1)))
      (let loop ((todo template)
                 (done '())
                 (result template))
        (if (= 1 (length todo))
            (list->vector result)
            (let* ((head (car todo))
                   (tail (cdr todo))
                   (next (append done (list head))))
              (loop tail
                    next
                    (append result tail next))))))))
```

`iota` is defined by SRFI-1.